# waiting for an action listener to execute while in a loop

Tags: java, for-loop, jbutton, actionlistener, wait

I'm making a math flashcard application that takes 20 answers and randomizes the question each time.

My Problem:  The for loop does not wait until the button is pressed.  I need to find a way to wait for the ActionListener to be executed before it goes through the loop again.

Please bear with me as I am quite new to Java.

Here is my current code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        Random numberOne = new Random();
        Random numberTwo = new Random();

        firstNumberInt = numberOne.nextInt(12) + 1;
        secondNumberInt = numberTwo.nextInt(12) + 1;

        firstNumber = Integer.toString(firstNumberInt);
        secondNumber = Integer.toString(secondNumberInt);

        firstNumberPrint.setText(firstNumber);
        secondNumberPrint.setText(secondNumber);


        answerBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String answerString = answerField.getText();

                try {
                    int answer = Integer.parseInt(answerString);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    error.setText("Number Cannot Be A Word");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I would not use a loop in the first place. Just make the action decide to print the next question or re-ask for the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActionListener` should be outside the loop and the loop should be within it.
Not the opposite.

```
     answerBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // Loop somewhere inside here

                String answerString = answerField.getText();

                try {
                    int answer = Integer.parseInt(answerString);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    error.setText("Number Cannot Be A Word");
                }
            }
        });
```

The code inside the overridden method inside the ActionListener class is being invoked every time the `Component` is interacted.

Comment: Thank you,  can't believe I messed up something that simple.